# webservice being redirecting to another webservice, this webservis to respond to first webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services

i have an application (client) A  and calls a service B, then the service B redirect it to service C, and service C responds to service A. how to implement this, can anybody answer this to me how to implement with asp.net ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use WCF, not ASP.NET for web services.

Second, instead of redirecting, why not simply have service B call service C and return the result?

---

Example:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string MyOperation(int i);
}


// ServiceB.cs
public class MyServiceB : IMyService
{
    public string MyOperation(int i)
    {
        var serviceCProxy = new ServiceReference.MyServiceClient();
        return serviceCProxy.MyOperation(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with this answer? The answer will never improve unless you say why it needs improvement.

Comment: how to call it in web method??

Comment: The same as any other client.

Comment: I don't know what you mean? This calls C and returns the result of that call back to "A".

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no direct connection between A and C, I don't think it's possible. And if A is a client and doesn't have server functionality there no way to connect it from C. But you may pass your data from C to B and then from B to A. It is something that is in use by many developers.